# CKFinder Cropping ciustomization

Tags: crop, ckfinder

i would like to change the size of the selection rectangle when cropping an image and force "keep proportions" button to true in CKFinder.

How could i achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in current version of CKFinder. https://github.com/ckfinder/ckfinder/issues/333